# How to make shrinkwrap work with responsive images?

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, shrinkwrap

I have an image inside a div and I'd like to shrinkwrap that by using:

```
<div class="shrinkwrap">
   <img src="image.jpg">
</div>

.shrinkwrap {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    padding: 10px;  
}
```

However, when I do it this way, the image is no longer responsive (I used `max-width: 100%`). It's responsive if I don't use the inline-block on the div but if I remove it, then my div doesn't shrink wrap around the image.

Any solution to this so that I can shrink wrap my image but keep it responsive?

Comment: do you want the image to be resized as the div or should it be cropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand; is this what you need?

http://jsfiddle.net/JtEuC/

All you need is the following code:

```
.shrinkwrap img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

And the .shrinkwrap div is always the size of the image.